# Make console calls in php and read output with colors

Tags: php, console, exec

In my php code I want to make console calls (e.g. 'git diff') via `exec()`, or `proc*` functions.

Is there any method to capture their output with colors?

---

Found a method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35011507/2450729

Comment: Might not be exactly what you're looking for, but I use this for converting svn diffs to html - http://plasticstare.com/plains/2011/03/17/svndiff2html-convert-svn-diffs-to-more-readable-html/

Answer (score 1):

You can ask `git` to always color output:

```
git -c color.diff=always diff
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the way to do it.

There is no method to do it straight through php. But you can capture colorized output by wrapping your command with `script -c <command>` tool. It will save colors.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using linux, you can use the **tput setat** command to highlight the output. Look this: http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_tput.php